# DC conductivity, linear response, "spectral representation"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, quantum-hall-effect

I am trying to derive the DC electrical conductivity using the pertubation theory in Interaction picture and linear response theory. If working in a energy eigen basis and using the density matrix, the Fourier transform of the susceptibility can be written as 
$\chi {(\omega )_{ij}} = i\int_0^\infty  {dt{e^{i\omega t}}\sum\limits_n {\left\langle n \right|{e^{ - \beta {{\hat H}_0}}}[{{\hat J}_j}(0),{{\hat J}_i}(t)]\left| n \right\rangle } } $

Then use $I = \sum\limits_n {\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|} $ and ${{\hat J}_i}(t) = {e^{i{{\hat H}_0}t}}{{\hat J}_i}(0){e^{ - i{{\hat H}_0}t}}$ . We can rewrite ${\sum\limits_n {\left\langle n \right|{e^{ - \beta {{\hat H}_0}}}[{{\hat J}_j}(0),{{\hat J}_i}(t)]\left| n \right\rangle } }$ as

$\sum\limits_{m,n} {{e^{ - {E_m}\beta }}\left[ {\left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| m \right\rangle {e^{i({E_m} - {E_n})t}} - \left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| m \right\rangle {e^{i({E_n} - {E_m})t}}} \right]} $

so

${\chi _{ij}}(\omega ) =  - i\int_0^\infty  {dt{e^{i\omega t}}} \sum\limits_{m,n} {{e^{ - {E_m}\beta }}\left[ {\left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| m \right\rangle {e^{i({E_m} - {E_n})t}} - \left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| m \right\rangle {e^{i({E_n} - {E_m})t}}} \right]} $

I see in literature, to make the integral converge, a complex frequency $\omega  + i\varepsilon $ is used to make the integrand vanish in $ + \infty $, therefore

$\begin{array}{l}
{\chi _{ij}}(\omega  + i\varepsilon ) = \sum\limits_{m,n} {{e^{ - {E_m}\beta }}\left[ {\frac{{\left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| m \right\rangle }}{{\omega  + i\varepsilon  + {E_m} - {E_n}}} - \frac{{\left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| m \right\rangle }}{{\omega  + i\varepsilon  + {E_n} - {E_m}}}{e^{i({E_n} - {E_m})t}}} \right]} \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \sum\limits_{m,n} {\frac{{\left\langle m \right|{{\hat J}_i}\left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right|{{\hat J}_j}\left| m \right\rangle }}{{\omega  + i\varepsilon  + {E_m} - {E_n}}}} ({e^{ - {E_m}\beta }} - {e^{ - {E_n}\beta }})
\end{array}$

My question is, since I am interested in the DC conductivity, I expect that finally I can remove ${i\varepsilon }$ in above expression when $\omega  \to 0$. But I am not sure how to do this since the integral is not well defined if there is no imaginary part in frequency.

On the other hand, if I just simply set $\omega  + i\varepsilon  = 0$, I seem to be able to find the correct form of conductivity formula used in the quantum hall effect.

Can somebody help?